# How to set all children font-size?

Tags: css

I have random html like below:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <p><span></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <span></span>
</article>
```

There may be any tag like `<section />` etc. Now I want to apply the `font-size` to **.8em** for the paragraphs.

So I can use `p{font-size: .8em;}` but if there is no `<p />` tag then on the `div<!--with no child p tag -->` I would use `div{font-size: .8em;}` but giving this style will resize the `font-size` of child `p` to `0.8*0.8=0.64em`. So the font-size of the paragraphs may vary.

Thus, how can I style all the paragraphs font-size static to `.8em`?

---

> paragraphs may be in `<p />, <div />, <span />` etc.

please note: p's font size is set to which I won't modify!

Comment: How do you define “paragraph”, when you apparently do not mean just a `p` element? In which sense could an inline element like `span` be a paragraph or contain a paragraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a base `font-size` for the root element (`<html>`), then use `rem` units

```
div { 
   font-size: .8rem;
}
```

This will ensure the same font-size for all div elements, even when they are nested (`em`'s instead will multiply the font-size)

`rem` support across browsers: http://caniuse.com/rem

*Edit* : I've applied the style to all div elements, of course apply the style to the paragraphs if you need it

Comment: no, rem is relative to the root element only. not to the parent font-size

Comment: downvoter cares to explain the reason of his downvote?

Comment: This introduces unnecessary browser dependency, since `rem` is not universally supported and there is surely a way to solve the problem *whatever it really is* without `rem`. Moreover, this does not set the font size of a `p` element nested inside `div` except possibly via inheritance.

Comment: the fact that rem is not universally supported is not a logical reason to downvote, since I've clearly highlighted the support. Indeed this example doesn't set the font-size of a paragraph: it's just an example to set the font-size of a generic element without the need to be careful about nested elements and `em`'s compounding.

Comment: Also "there's surely a way to solve the problem whatever it really is without using <X>" is not a logical reason itself for a downvote. Anyway I do respect your opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

You could reset the children's `font-size` like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DZhZP/5/)**

CSS:

```
div{font-size:.8em;}
p{font-size:.8em;}
div > p,div > div{font-size:1em;}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you have any tag nested or child you could do this:
(I although recomend you use the above solution specifying the font-size for each case you come up with)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DZhZP/8/)**

CSS:

```
*{
    font-size:0.8em;
}
*>*{
    font-size:1em;
}
```

Comment: what if span, article, section, etc. only?

Comment: @C-link Well you can do it on any child, I will update my answer to follow these tags.

Comment: uhum! by following the tags? notice there may be any tag!

Answer (score -2):

If you use jQuery, you can use brute force

```js
$('article').find('*').css('font-size', '1em')
```

If you want to consider that paragraphs are only inside `<p>, <div>, <span>`, you may filter

```js
$('article').find('p, div, span').css('font-size', '1em')
```